# how to change value on method in java?

Tags: java, string

You can only change `void degitir()`  method.
Can not add anything.
Write only this method  `void degitir()`

How to change the `String X`

```
static void degitir(String s){
    //Only here can be written
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    String X = "ahmet";
    System.out.println("X = " + X);
    degitir(X);
    System.out.println("X = " + X);
}
```

Comment: it's not possible, you cannot

Comment: strings are immutable

Comment: @lordkain And how exactly do you pass something by reference in Java?

Comment: @Joffrey Use AtomicReference for example

Comment: @talex Well any wrapper object would do, obviously, but I was surprised by the wording "pass by reference", which, IMO, is not very appropriate here.

Comment: @Joffrey In some sense it is correct answer. AtomicReference is part of Java and is a reference. And you can pass it. So formally you can pass something by reference :)

Comment: @talex I wouldn't say `AtomicReference` is a reference. It is a wrapper object that is passed by value. And that object happens to contain a reference to another object. But I agree I'm being picky here ^^ Anyway, I just wanted to point out that the original comment was misleading (for C programmers for instance), so that someone like you would clarify ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **CAN** change the value of a `String`. Use reflection:

```
static void degitir(String s)
{
    try
    {
        final char [] newValue = "Hello world".toCharArray();

        Field f = String.class.getDeclaredField("count");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(s, newValue.length);

        f = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(s, newValue);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This will display

```
X = ahmet

X = Hello world
```

without the need to return a `String`.

Answer (score 7):

String is immutable therefore you cannot change its value.

The only thing you can do is assigning the variable to an other string.

Answer (score 5):

There's a way but it violates what all the other answers point out and, therefore, should be avoided. What you're trying to do can be accomplished via reflection:

```
static void degitir(String s){
    try{
        java.lang.reflect.Field field = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");  
        field.setAccessible(true);  

        char[] value = (char[])field.get(s);
        value[0] = 'J';  
        value[1] = 'a';  
        value[2] = 'v';  
        value[3] = 'a';  
        value[4] = '!'; 

    }catch(Exception e){
        // Add message.
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args){

    String X = "ahmet";
    System.out.println("X = " + X);
    degitir(X);
    System.out.println("X = " + X);
}
```

Comment: Each time someone used reflection this way, a new Justin Bieber is born.

Comment: And you must reset `hash` field to `0` or else you break it contract

Comment: @Joffrey. I agree. I just showing a way to do accomplish that.

Comment: @Augusto No offense intended, you are the only one here who actually answered the question :) I was just emphasizing the fact that this is a bad idea -which you have done too.

Comment: None taken. I also dislike this way of handling objects. In this case it breaks the very nature of String objects.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot update a local variable `X` from a static context.

```
static void degitir(String s){
  //Only here can be written
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  String X = "ahmet";
  System.out.println("X = " + X);
  degitir(X); // <-- cannot modify the X, it's local to main.
  System.out.println("X = " + X);
}
```

But, you could move `X` -

```
static void degitir(){
  X = "Like so";
}
private static String X = "ahmet";

public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("X = " + X);
  degitir(); // <-- can modify the static X.
  System.out.println("X = " + X);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable, so if you want to 'change' your string, you could return a different String in your method and assigning it to your variable x.

```
static String degitit(String s){
    return "aDifferent String";
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
  String X = "ahmet";
  System.out.println("X = " + X);
  X = degitir(X);
  System.out.println("X = " + X);
}
```

Comment: NOT changed any code write only there " //Only here can be written "

Comment: Then it is not possible since you are using a String object, which is immutable.